# Inserting a sum answer

Tags: mysql, sum, addition

I'm trying to add a row that will have a total in mysql.  Below is what I am looking to achieve, in Excel this would be `=SUM(C2:C3)` but I need the function to work out of mysql.  Is this even possible.

```
SchoolName    /  TeacherName    / ObservationTimeInMinutes

EMMERTONSchool  /Gordon,Rose    /    28

EMMERTONSchool/ Mondragon,Pat  /    13
```

`Total  41`, this is what I would like to add to my output

Comment: MySQL also has a [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in mysql syntax. Most of the dbms vendors have some functions to do this in one query, but you can always do:

```
select schoolname, Teachername, ObservationTimeInMinutes from yourTable
UNION 
select 'total', '', sum(OberservatonTimeInMinutes) from yourTable
```

Depending on your tablestructure you might need group by clause.